# Exponential Values are getting Loaded into Hive table on Sqoop Import

Tags: sql-server-2008, hive, floating-point, precision, sqoop

I have imported table from SQL server to Hive, whereas float field from SQL server is getting converted to double into hive. And the few of the values are loaded with exponential format.

**Ex.**

Value from Table= 10488666.6666667

```
Value loaded into Hive= 1.0488666666666666E7
```

Also there is one more issue observed for same field where extra precisions are getting added,

**Ex**.  Value from table= 3688666.66666667

```
     Value from Hive table= 3688666.6666666665
```

Can someone suggest me how to get rid of this and load the values as it is from RDBMS to Hive ,since it will be ease to query in hive.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on what you are seeing on JDBC client, Hive shell.

See actual data in HDFS of your hive table. To check this go to hive shell and fire

```
show create table tablename
```

Check location key and go to hdfs and check actual data. It should be same.

Comment: yes,HDFS also contains exponential values..so my question is how to store the values as it is in HDFS?

Comment: @Priya.A Aren't your values are same in SQL Server and HDFS?

Comment: @Priya.A  How are you seeing data in SQL Server?

Comment: Nope they are not same.I am viewing the data using SQL server mgt. studio.

Comment: @Priya.A can you perform something like create data script in SQL server mgt? Check data?

Comment: I have generated data script for table where i could c '10488666.666666666' has been inserted through insert command and RDBMS has '10488666.6666667' and in HDFS it is stored as 1.0488666666666666E7

Comment: @Priya.A that's okay. What about other value `3688666.66666667`?

Comment: Its inserted as 3688666.6666666665 same is been reflected in hive.

Comment: @Priya.A you got the point. You did not lose precision here. For smaller numbers data is same. For larger number hive is converting it into the Exponential format. If you can check data form SQL server shell or something it should also be exponential.

Comment: Yes, I got it.But i unable to view the data on shell,so as a alternative i have created table in mysql and exported the same HDFS data to mysql table.Where i have defined this field as Double and the value is loaded as  10488666.6667 .This i have checked on mysql shell.

Answer (score 0):

I did face such issue in the past, an easy way out would be use to "String" in hive table. The system does put additional effort to convert on the fly, however, it should be negligible.

Comment: I have tried this, but it could not resolve my issue :(

Comment: may I know what tool you are using for the transfer - sqoop?